# Wordpress editor removes all the linefeed characters with WP-Markdown and Syntax Highlighter evolved

Tags: editor, code, markdown

I have [WP-Markdown](http://www.stephenharris.info/) and [SyntaxHighlighter Evolved](http://www.viper007bond.com/wordpress-plugins/syntaxhighlighter/) wordpress plugins installed.

The issue is that when I write the code, and click the "Update" button, I have the code reformatted.

```
[ruby] 
class Foo < Bar 
    def hello 
        puts "Hello World!" 
    end 
end 
[/ruby]
```

This is the modified code.

```
[ruby] class Foo < Bar def hello puts "Hello World!" end end [/ruby]
```

There is no change without the `[ruby]` tag.

```
class Foo < Bar 
    def hello puts "Hello World!" 
    end 
end
```

How can I prevent the code modification? I tried following actions to get the same results.

- I checked  `Disable the visual editor when writing`
- I tried [Xhanch My Advanced Settings](http://chriscarvache.com/2010-10/wordpress/prevent-wordpress-from-changing-your-code/)  plugin.
- I tried [CKEditor For WordPress](http://wordpress.org/plugins/ckeditor-for-wordpress/)
- I used Safari and Chrome web browser.